# Take photo in unity c#

Tags: unity-game-engine, screenshot, photo

I'm trying to build a program that takes your photo and places it with a different background, like a monument or so. So far, I was able to turn the camera on when I start the project with this code

```
 webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
 rawImage.texture = webcamTexture;
 rawImage.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
 webcamTexture.Play();
 Texture2D PhotoTaken = new Texture2D (webcamTexture.width, webcamTexture.height);
 PhotoTaken.SetPixels (webcamTexture.GetPixels ());
 PhotoTaken.Apply ();
```

However, I can't take a screenshot or photo because it always ends up all black. I've tried different codes but nothing is working. Can someone please help? Thanks

EDIT

After some tries, this is the code I have:

```
WebCamTexture webcamTexture;
public RawImage rawImage;


void Start () {
    webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
    rawImage.texture = webcamTexture;
    rawImage.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
    webcamTexture.Play();

    RenderTexture texture= new RenderTexture(webcamTexture.width, webcamTexture.height,0); 
    Graphics.Blit(webcamTexture, texture);

    Button btn = yourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    btn.onClick.AddListener(OnClick);

}

public IEnumerator Coroutine(){

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
}

public void OnClick() {

    var width = 767;
    var height = 575;

    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, height);
    texture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
    texture.Apply();

    // Encode texture into PNG
    var bytes = texture.EncodeToPNG();
    //Destroy(texture);


    File.WriteAllBytes (Application.dataPath + "/../SavedScreen.png", bytes);

    }
```

and with this next code the screenshot is taken, but it takes a photo of the whole thing, and not just a bit of the screen.

```
void Start()
{
    // Set the playback framerate!
    // (real time doesn't influence time anymore)
    Time.captureFramerate = frameRate;

    // Find a folder that doesn't exist yet by appending numbers!
    realFolder = folder;
    int count = 1;
    while (System.IO.Directory.Exists(realFolder))
    {
        realFolder = folder + count;
        count++;
    }
    // Create the folder
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(realFolder);
}

void Update()
{
    // name is "realFolder/shot 0005.png"
    var name = string.Format("{0}/shot {1:D04}.png", realFolder, Time.frameCount);

    // Capture the screenshot
    Application.CaptureScreenshot(name, sizeMultiplier);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can take a screenshot like this in `Unity`

```
    Application.CaptureScreenshot("Screenshot.png");
```

[Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html)

**EDIT 1**
To take a screenshot on a specific part of the screen use the following script:

```
 var width = 400;
 var height = 300;
 var startX = 200;
 var startY = 100;
 var tex = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

 tex.ReadPixels (Rect(startX, startY, width, height), 0, 0);
 tex.Apply ();

 // Encode texture into PNG
 var bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
 Destroy(tex);

 File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../SavedScreen.png", bytes);
```

[Reference](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/taking-screenshot-of-partial-area.54189/)

Comment: What if I don't want the whole screen to appear in the screenshot? Just one part

Comment: I'm sorry if I seem really dumb, but I'm really new to this. But it doesn't work. The Rect part has an error and after a lot os tries I don't know what to do.

Comment: Could you update your question with the code you tried?

Comment: Just updated the question with the new code. It works, but with the whole screen. I have no idea what I can do to fix it

Comment: Where do you call the method `OnRenderImage`?

Comment: I don't. Edited to what I really have now. Too many codes that i'm trying and I'm getting confused. Sorry.

Comment: So you now have a picture named `SavedScreen.png` that is of the entire screen?

Comment: Because I apparently have two scripts saving a screenshot, I have a picture named SavedScreen.png all white (from the first script) and in a folder named ScreenshotMovieOutput that takes a picture of the entire screen(from the second script).

Comment: Could you remove `PhotoTaken` and use only `texture` in your first script, because you are not Encoding correctly.

Comment: Even now, all white. The size it's what I wrote in the width and height var but it's white.

Comment: Could you also remove the code from the `Update` method and make a dedicated method with a button click?

Comment: For the method "readPixel", you'd better use a coroutine and wait for the end of frame, or it console will throw you an error.

Comment: Now, it takes the screenshot when I click the button, however, it's still white. The coroutine part, I don't know exacly if it's like that, maybe it's not, but as I told before, I'm really new to this.